# Upgrading Directus on a server using Docker Compose and managing database compatibility

Tags: redis, postgis, directus

I recently set up Directus on my server using the Docker Compose method described in the Docker Guide.

I have also installed a security plugin to check for potential issues with my images. Currently, the Postgis [13-master] and redis:6 versions have been reported as having some security concerns. Would you recommend staying on this version or upgrading to a different one? If upgrading is necessary, what steps can I take to ensure compatibility with the new database version?